# Link opening in download pop-up window but doesn't work when copied and pasted

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape and download files from search results displayed when just clicking the search button on https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/search.  When the search results are displayed, the links look like https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/filedownload?fileid=823F0FAB-E23A-CD5B-9FDD-7B3B7A700000 as an example.  Clicking on this link on the search results page forces a download (content-disposition: attachment).  However, I am saving the search results as an html page and then scraping the links.  I am trying to get the file associated with the link and store it locally however my code isn't working.

```
#!/usr/local/bin python3

import os
import sys
import psycopg2
from pathlib import Path
import urllib.request
import requests


session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(
        {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"}
    )
r1 = session.get("https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/search", verify=False)

dl_url = "https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/filedownload?fileid=020E6084-66E2-5005-8110-C31FAFC91712"

req = session.get(dl_url, verify=False)

with open("dl_url", "wb") as outfile:
  outfile.write(req.content)
```

I am not able to download the file contents at all (pdf, docx etc).  The code above is just to try and solve the local download issue.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a json post request.  Original URL won't work.